# javascript code in html to js file

Tags: javascript, html

I am struggling with the following problem.

I have made a memorygame with javascrpt for school.It all works fine, but my teacher told me that i can not have on line of javascript in my HTML, like this :

**HTML :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
        <title>Memory spelen</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
        <div id="memory_board"></div>
        <script>newBoard();</script>
   </body>
</html>
```

The `newBoard()` is applied to the memory_board div. How can i take this little piece of script out of my HTML file and place it in my js file, to still function properly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does `newBoard` do? Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net for us?

Comment: that piece of code will work like it was doing in your html if you don't jave server generated ids... else you will need a polyfill for those ids

Answer (score 2):

Inside of your javascript.js put this

```
window.onload = function {

    // content of your script

    var newBoard = function(){
        // the new updated newBoard() function from below
    }

    // other parts of your script

    if(window.location.href == 'your-url') {
        // now, after the newBoard() has been updated
        // the next to lines are not needed 
        // var board = document.getElementById('memory_board');            
        // board.innerHTML = newBoard();
        // just call the function
        newBoard();
    }
};
```

UPDATE

I just took a look at your old [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2GW3k/5/) and I changed your `newBoard` function to this

```
function newBoard(){
    tiles_flipped = 0;
    var output = '';
    memory_array.memory_tile_shuffle();
    for(var i = 0; i < memory_array.length; i++){
        var div = document.createElement('DIV');
        div.id =  "tile_" + i;
        (function(div,i){
            div.onclick = function() {
                memoryFlipTile(this, memory_array[i]);
            };
        }(div,i));
        document.getElementById('memory_board').appendChild(div);
    }
}
```

Check the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2GW3k/7/).

Comment: but what if you don't want this to run on each page? and you insert that js in a template layout?

Comment: Thanks, the problem still is that my javascript code doesn't apply to the <div>memory_board</div> in my HTML.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2GW3k/5/ this is my full code. If you like, please check it. Would be extremely helpful!

Comment: @hex494D49 this is better ;) ... all the time cases like this can appear so you should better be prepared for it

Comment: @HellBaby Check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/2GW3k/6/) And don't forget, in your own script you should enclose all of your code within window.onload event - just as I stated in my answer.

Comment: @HellBaby Check the updated answer; now you have a working program / game :)

Answer (score 1):

try to put it like this in external js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   newBoard();
});
```

Comment: he want to do it on load of particular div. add filter to follow his requirement

Answer (score 1):

It looks that you need to call newBoard() method  on onload event of memory_board div , You can do this in following ways:

```
<div id="memory_board" onload="javascript:newBoard()"  ></div>  // use onload event of memory_board
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use onload function on the javascript. It will call the function when all the HTML tag is loaded on the screen.